# C# Z3 (Version 4.3) ParseSMTLIB2String says "unsupported"

Tags: c#, z3

I use the following code to parse the string to Z3, however it warnings that unspported.

```
string str = "(set-option :fixedpoint.engine datalog)\n(declare-rel edge ( (_ BitVec 2) (_ BitVec 2)))\n(declare-var a (_ BitVec 2))\n(declare-var c (_ BitVec 2))\n(declare-var b (_ BitVec 2))\n\n(rule (=> ( edge a  b  )( edge a  c  )))\n(rule ( edge #b00  #b01  ))\n(rule ( edge #b01  #b10  ))\n(rule ( edge #b10  #b11  ))";

Context ctx = new Context(new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                          {
                                              {"MODEL", "true"}
                                          });
ctx.ParseSMTLIB2String(str);
```

The errors are shown like below:
[image]

Not sure where my problem is, can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

declare-rel, declare-var, rule and query are not SMT-LIB2 commands. 
The SMT2 parser only supports SMT-LIB2 format and returns the assertions
in the file or string as an expression.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way to parse it?